# Why should I use 'underbar(_)' for getting my function done?

Tags: javascript

I was studying inheritance of javascript and made a function to test it.
Here is the code:

```
function subClass(obj) {
    const parent = (this === window) ? Function : this;
    const F = function() {};

    const child = function() {
        const _parent = child.parent;
        
        if(_parent && _parent !== Function) {
            _parent.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        if(child.prototype._init) {
            child.prototype._init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };

    F.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new F();
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
    child.parent = parent;
    child.subClass = arguments.callee;

    for (let i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            child.prototype[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }

    return child;
}
```

Then I made a sample object to adapt the function subClass. :

```
const person_obj = {
    _init: function() {
        console.log("person init");
    },
    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    },
    setName: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
};
```

Finally, here is the output code. :

```
const Person = subClass(person_obj);
const person = new Person();
person.setName("dorae");
console.log(person.getName());
```

Here is the question.
What I want as a result for *console.log(person.getName());* is **dorae**,

but instead empty space comes out as a result.

However, when I change two '**this.name**'s in person_obj to '**this._name**',
the exact result '**dorae**' comes out.

Even though I came up to the result what I wanted,
I couldn't get the reason why I got the result.

I would appreciate if you let me know the reason why I get the answer only
when I use the underbar in front of the variable.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you make the prototype that of `Function` so you clash with [`Function#name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). I'm not really sure why you do any of this, though. That's not at all normal way to set up inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Actually, I was reading kind of old javascript book and all the stuff above are from the book. I tried to follow the book and encountered the issue. Anyway, I could understand why the problem happened thanks to your comment. Thank you! :)